# What is wrong with my string comparison function?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I've made it my goal to write all my functions recursively so that I appear smarter. For fun, I came up with a string comparison function

```
#include <iostream>

int string_compare ( char * s1, char * s2 ) 
{
    int retval;
    switch ( s1 ? 1 : 0 + s2 ? 2 : 0 )
    {
       case 0 : retval = 1; break; 
       case 1 :  
       case 2 : retval = 0; break; 
       case 3 : retval = *s1 == *s2 ? string_compare(++s1,++s2) : 0; break;
    }
    return retval;
}

int main ( )
{
    char str1 [] = "hey there",
         str2 [] = "hey there";
    std::cout << string_compare(str1,str2);
}
```

but it's wrong as the above code is printing `0` instead of the expect `1`. What's the problem?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Understanding recursion is great, but using recursion everywhere shows you don't understand recursion.

Comment: _"I've made it my goal to write all my functions recursively so that I appear smarter."_ Wrong premise.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not sure if you're familiar with modern-day programming interviews, but they're all about memorizing fancy, and sometimes completely incorrect, ways of solving useless challenges so as to appear smart. And be sure to throw around the term "hash table" as places like Amazon have a checklist of CS buzzwords that they're looking for.

Comment: Writing code that seems "smart" can be fun, but such code is nowhere near as valuable as code that simple and does the same thing.

Comment: Since `s1` is a _string_, it cannot be `NULL`, so why does code do `s1 ?...`? `s1`, as a _string_, will always be true.

Comment: @SubparWebDev I have recently gone through an job search in which I did many technical interviews and never once was I asked to do anything similar to solving fancy but useless challenges. They asked me what I knew about certain topics and technologies and I showed them what I knew. Eventually I found a job where what they were looking for was what I knew, and they offered me the job. Also, if I were asked stupid useless questions or if they wanted me to write fancy but wrong code I wouldn't accept a job offer from them.

Comment: What if you have to compare ("", "")?

Comment: In many situations, iterations (loops) are much easier for a compiler to optimize and a processor to execute.  A *smart* programmer writes code that is easy to maintain, correct and robust.  Some shops will replace complex "smart" code with code that is simpler and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Operator `+` [has precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) over operator `?:`. Use parenthesis.

```
switch ( (s1 ? 1 : 0) + (s2 ? 2 : 0) )
```

---

#### Full correction

For a complete, working C-string recursive comparison function, here is an implementation:

```
/// @retval -1 iff sting s1 is before s2
/// @retval  0 iff sting s1 is equal to s2
/// @retval +1 iff sting s1 is afters2
int string_compare(const char* s1, const char* s2)
{
    if (*s1 > *s2) return 1;
    if (*s1 < *s2) return -1;

    if (*s1 == 0)
        return 0; // *s1 == *s2 == '\0'

    return string_compare(++s1, ++s2);
}
```

The idea is to define the result as a recursive statement:

- An empty string is less than any non-empty string;
- If both `s1` and `s2` are empty, `s1 == s2`;
- If the first character of `s1` is less than the one of `s2`, `s1 < s2`;
- If the first character of `s1` is greater than the one of `s2`, `s1 > s2`;
- If the first character of `s1` is equal to the one of `s2`,,
  the order of `S1` and `s2` is the same as the order of those string, their first character taken off.

#### Demonstration

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

namespace
{
    int string_compare(const char* s1, const char* s2)
    {
        if (*s1 > *s2) return 1;
        if (*s1 < *s2) return -1;

        if (*s1 == 0)
            return 0; // *s1 == *s2 == '\0'

        return string_compare(++s1, ++s2);
    }
}

int main()
{
    const char* words[] = {
        "recursive",
        "compare",
        "function",
        "for",
        "C",
        "string",
        "is",
        "really",
        "useless",
        "dont",
        "you",
        "think",
        " ",
        "recursive"
    };

    std::sort(std::begin(words), std::end(words), [](auto lhs, auto rhs){ return string_compare(lhs, rhs) < 0;});

    for (auto s : words)
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

#### Output

```
 
C
compare
dont
for
function
is
really
recursive
recursive
string
think
useless
you
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46b227d85a5c03f7)</kbd>

Comment: @SubparWebDev I felt wrong to get an accepted answer for a partial comment. You're code is broken at almost every line, so I took it upon myself to provide a rewriting from the bottom-up.

Answer (score 6):

Use parents (and fix condition):

```
(*s1 ? 1 : 0) + (*s2 ? 2 : 0)
```

Comment: That is always 3 unless `s1` or `s2` are NULL, as chux points out in a comment to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

The `+` operator has greater precedence over `?:` operator. It is always better to use parenthesis.

```
switch ((s1 ? 1:0) + (s2 ? 2:0))
```

You can refer to [this](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm).